# Maven собственный удаленный репозиторий

Tags: apache, maven, repository

Привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно создать репозиторий на удаленном сервере и добавлять в него jar для небольшой команды с помощью Maven? Варианты с Nexus не разрешены...

Maven поставил на сервере. Пробовал добавить по следующей команде из локальной машины на удаленный сервер:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/andy/IdeaProjects/testmaven/target/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.it -DartifactId=test -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Получил следующую ошибку в терминале:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The specified file '/home/andy/IdeaProjects/testmaven/target/test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' not exists -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```